# Adding a swipe indication for nested scroll view in android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to add an indicator for the nested scroll view to indicate that the view can swipe up.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFT27.jpg) my view consists of a nested scroll view and recycles view for showing data. i have tried different options, but I cannot add the bar at the top of the scroll view without impacting the data shown by the recycle view. I have also attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ8ER.jpg) for showing the view I want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default option for creating this, you have to create custom view like below.

```
<View
 android:id="@+id/view"
 android:layout_width="80dp"
 android:layout_height="4dp"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:background="@color/gray" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).